# Facebook send dialog send private mesage, Error: This attachment may have been removed

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, salesforce, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using to **Force.com Facebook toolkit** to send message to facebook. I am able to send message **using java script** in facebook, below is my java script code

```
<script> 
      function closewindow(){
          window.close();
      }
      FB.init({appId: '{!id}', status: true, cookie: true});
      function postToFeed() {
        var obj = {
          method: 'send',
          to: '{!fbuserid}', 
          link: '{!$CurrentPage.URL}',
          description: 'Testing'
        };
        function callback(response) {
            if (response['post_id']) {
                var postId = response['post_id'].split('_')[1];
                document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 
                    "Posted to your wall. "+
                    "<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?"+
                    "id={!me.id}&v=wall&story_fbid="+postId+"\">View your post</a>";
            }
        }
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }
  </script>
```

The message which is received in facebook comes with a error message as shown in picture below.

Message received look like-

> Hi
>   
> This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you.

How can I remove this error from my message? Also is there a way to send message using graph api?

Answer (score 0):

First This error means that the person you are trying to send message has not granted you permission to send message. To do this the recipient must allow you to send message.

Second you can only send message through Javascript as Facebook does not allow to send it through Graph API. But you can read mailbox through Graph API. Follow this link:

[Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/message/)

Comment: Despite of error, my message is delivered to user. Is there any way to remove the error.

Comment: What exactly the error message is that comes from Facebook? You can check the specific error code and ignore it if it's not breaking the code functionality.

Comment: you can check the warning or error. I have specified it above in my code.

Comment: Well if that error comes from Facebook it means message is not delivered.

Comment: but my message is delivered i can see it

Comment: Seems funny. Good Luck :)

Comment: hey, i also need to login in my facebook account for sending message.
is there a way not to login or provide auto login.

Comment: No you must need to Login to send message or it will ask automatically to Login. You cannot bypass this step. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

Comment: Is there a way we can provide auto login by provide email and password in our code before sending message.

Comment: Nope. You can call login function to check login status and then ask for login through Dialog. For this you should read following links in detail. 

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2012/05/08/how-to--improve-the-experience-for-returning-users/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/